# Another web server is already running. XAMPP apache [UBUNTU]

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I installed XAMPP in my Ubuntu version. I start apache with :

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

and I read in my console this error:

```
Another web server is already running
```

So I think to modify the port's values `httpd.conf` and `httpd-ssl.conf`, 
in details I have mofidy port:

```
80--->1580 (httpd.conf)
443-->4443 (httpd-ssl.conf)
```

I closed apache with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

And After I do:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

But I obtain:

[APACHE] Another web server is already running

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how i solved it on Pop OS:

1. Run `sudo netstat -nap | grep :80` to get the pid of what's running on port 80

   You should get an output similar to:

   *tcp6   0   0  :::80      :::*    LISTEN 1166/apache2*
2. Note the pid. In this case apache2 is running on pid **1166**
3. Run `sudo kill 1166`. Be sure to replace 1166 with the actual pid from the output of command 1.
4. Start apache again `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`. This time it should start with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop

Then restart

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Comment: it's not this the problem!

Comment: You tried it but it didnt work? You normally need to shutdown all the services before you can start lampp. (Apache, Mysql, Proftpd is part of Lampp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
sudo su
```

Type your password:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

> [ ok ] Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.

After that, you can try to run it again by typing:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start
```

> Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.9-0...
>
> XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
>
> XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
>
> XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem, I tried everything. Finally, I **disabled ssl** for Apache and it worked.

```
[root@localhost lampp]# /opt/lampp/xampp disablessl
```